# Confusion C begining

Tags: c, arrays, char, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
 char a[250];
 char c1[1],c2[1];
int n,i;


printf("Give text: ");
gets(a);

printf("Give c1: ");
gets(c1);
  printf("Give c2: ");
 gets(c2);

n=strlen(a);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(a[i]==c1)
 {
      a[i]=c2;
   }
  if(a[i]==c2)
 {
    a[i]=c1;
   }
   }
     printf("%s",a);
return 0;
}
```

In a text I need to switch `c1` with `c2` and reverse,
but when I start the program after I give a, `c1`, `c2` nothing happened.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun, deprecated in C99 and removed from C11.

Comment: `gets(c1);` with `char c1[1]` is bad because this will only accept zero characters + terminating null character. `a[i]=c2;` and `a[i]=c1;` looks weird because it is assigning what is converted from the pointer converted from the array.

Comment: You want to read on how C-"string" are implemented. A C-"string" defined `char c[1]` can hold nothing more then the "emtpy-string": `""`.

Comment: And pleeease, properly indent your code, at least prior presenting it to the world for reading ... :-(

Comment: I mean what possessed you to 'char c1[1],c2[1]; ???   Were you a stingy accountant in another life?  Shtap with the bean-counting, nd besides, [1] is just silly anyway, as others have pointed out:(

Comment: Nitpicking: `strlen()` doesn't return a signed integer but an `unsigned`, typically for recent C compilers a `size_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [don't use `gets()`, it's inherently dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917), use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

On top of that, when you used `gets(c1)`, `c1` being an one-element array, you already overrun the allocated memory which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, you have `c1` and `c2` as one-element arrays, which are not wrong but neither required. Define them as simple `char` variables

```
char c1;
char c2;
```

and use them like

```
 scanf(" %c", &c1);  // mind the space and don't forget to to check the return 
 scanf(" %c", &c2);  // value of scanf() to ensure proper scanning.
```

After that, the check for `a[i] == c2` should come as `else` construct, otherwise, you'll be overwriting the previous operation. Something like

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(a[i]==c1)
   {
      a[i]=c2;
   }
  else if(a[i]==c2)
   {
    a[i]=c1;
   }
}
```

Comment: As it stands `&c1` evaluates to `char**`. `"%c"` expects a `char*`.

Comment: @alk erm... din't I mention `define them as simple char variables and use them like` already? :)

Comment: Indeed, you did. Please excuse ... :}

Answer (score 0):

- `gets()` shouldn't be used because it has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun, is deprecated in C99 and is removed from C11.
- `c1` and `c2` have insufficient buffer size.
- You should check if readings are successful.
- You should dereference `c1` and `c2` before compareing to retrieve characters read.
- You should use `else if`, or the modified character will be modified again.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* this is a simple implementation and the buffer for \n is wasted */
char* safer_gets(char* buf, size_t size){
  char* lf;
  if (fgets(buf, size, stdin) == NULL) return NULL;
  if ((lf = strchr(buf, '\n')) != NULL) *lf = '\0';
  return buf;
}

int main()
{
  char a[250];
  char c1[4],c2[4]; /* need at least 3 elements due to the inefficient implementation of safer_gets */
  int n,i;


  printf("Give text: ");
  if(safer_gets(a, sizeof(a)) == NULL)
  {
    fputs("read a error\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }

  printf("Give c1: ");
  if(safer_gets(c1, sizeof(c1)) == NULL)
  {
    fputs("read c1 error\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
  printf("Give c2: ");
  if(safer_gets(c2, sizeof(c2)) == NULL)
  {
    fputs("read c2 error\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }

  n=strlen(a);

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    if(a[i]==*c1)
    {
      a[i]=*c2;
    }
    else if(a[i]==*c2)
    {
      a[i]=*c1;
    }
  }
  printf("%s",a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `c[4]`? One for the `char`, one for the `\n` and one for the `0`-terminator gives 3. :-S Is the 4th the famous Angst-Byte? ;-)

Comment: And hmhm, and I doubt that seeing `*c1` makes things easier to understand then just finding a `c[0]`...